# How do I initialize and fill a linked list in Eiffel?

Tags: eiffel, eiffel-studio-18

Here's what I have so far.

```
create {LINKED_LIST[INTEGER]} list.make
from
    i := 0
    list.start
until
    i = 11
loop
    list.put(i)
    i := i + 1
    list.forth
end
```

The debugger points to line list.put(i). I think the problem is that list is not properly initialized? I'm having a bit of an issue with figuring out how to use linked_list because I can't find any proper tutorial to help with. As you can see, I am just trying to write a LINKED_LIST program that adds numbers [0,10] in a linked list. Not a school project. Just practicing ahead of an upcoming course. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the comments of the features that are used in the original example:

1. `LIST.put (v: like item)`: Replace current item by `v`.
2. `LIST.start`: Move cursor to first position.
3. `LIST.forth`: Move to next position.

The newly created list is empty. Therefore, there are no items that can be replaced by calling `put`. This explains why the debugger stops at the feature `put`: the precondition of the feature is violated.

Looking at the interface view of the class `LIST`, there is a feature clause `Element change` with the following features:

- `append (s: SEQUENCE [G])`: Append a copy of `s`.
- `extend (v: G)`: Add a new occurrence of `v`.
- `fill (other: CONTAINER [G])`: Fill with as many items of `other` as possible.
- `force (v: like item)`: Add `v` to end.
- `put (v: like item)`: Replace current item by `v`.
- `sequence_put (v: like item)`: Add `v` to end.
- `put_i_th (v: like item; i: INTEGER_32)`: Put `v` at `i`-th position.
- `replace (v: G)`: Replace current item by `v`.

Because we are talking about a feature to add a new element to the end of the list, only the following ones are suitable: `extend`, `force`, `sequence_put`. The [idiomatic feature name](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffel/Style_Guidelines#Standard_names) for this case is `extend`.

Taking this into account, the original loop becomes:

```
from
    i := 0
until
    i = 11
loop
    list.extend (i)
    i := i + 1
end
```